# Collision not happening between two 2D game objects, they pass through each other if one of them is moved

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

[My Problem can be seen through this video..](https://youtu.be/jDPqk-AmY4Y)

You will be able to see in the link above that until I move rod down every thing works well but as soon as I move down the burger gets stuck in the rod. Help me I want it to just deflect off the surface. Something like ping pong game....

For deflection I used the following snippet of code.

```
foreach (Bar rod in bar)
{               
    if(rod.CollisionRectangle.Intersects(GameBall.CollisionRectangle))
    {
        GameBall.speed *= -1;
        Console.WriteLine("game" + GameBall.speed);                  
    }
}
```

Here gameball refers to the burger and rod refers to the images at the top and the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be happening is that the rod is overlapping the ball *more* than the ball is moving in one frame. In other words, if the ball is moving 3 pixels per frame but the objects are overlapping by 5 pixels they won't be able to come out of collision by simply changing direction. You'll need to actually *move* the ball out of collision first.

That said, collision detection and response is always tricky code to write. The key is to separate the detection code from the response code.

In other words. For every frame:

1. Detect all collisions
2. Move all objects

What you're doing now is moving things during the detection phase. That's going to lead to trouble when 2 objects are moving towards each other.

There's way more material on this subject than I can fit into an answer. I suggest looking around for tutorials on AABB collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

Is your CollisionRectangle the built in Rectangle class in MonoGame/XNA?

Assuming it is and the loop is in Update, maybe you could try inserting a break so that it'll stop updating the gameball speed immediately after the first change. This is because the game is updated 60 times per second, there condition might be true for a few miliseconds or so when the game is updating.

```
foreach (Bar rod in bar)
{
    if(rod.CollisionRectangle.Intersects(GameBall.CollisionRectangle))
    {
        GameBall.speed *= -1;
        Console.WriteLine("game" + GameBall.speed);
        break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work and maybe i can try it in a new project when i'm free.

Answer (score 0):

When the ball intersect with the bar, you change the direction but the collision is still here so maybe you can try this:

```
foreach (Bar rod in bar)
{               
        if(rod.CollisionRectangle.Intersects(GameBall.CollisionRectangle))
        {
            GameBall.speed *= -1;

            // Reset position of the ball
            // Something like :
            // For the top bar
            Gameball.y = rod.y + rod.height;

            // For the bottom bar
            // Gameball.y = rod.y - Gameball.height

            Console.WriteLine("game" + GameBall.speed);                  

        }
    }
```